# updateing a mysql record

Tags: mysql, sql-update

i must be over tired again as i just can not PINPOINT what is wrong with my query

what is happening in the code is this. a datagridview is used for a user to pick what they want to be displayed on a button. lets say button 5 we want to be APPLES. Apples will be selected in the datagridview and the sender tells what button to put APPLES on. Next we need to capture the buttons name from sender.name and update the database for apples BTN_NAME now = Btn_cat5

i hope i'm clear here. sorry if i am not, i am DEAD TIRED. Thanks for any help in advance. i know its in my SQL statment as i get a syntax error. just can't seem to see what i did wrong.

```
Private Sub btn_Cat1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Cat1.Click, btn_Cat2.Click, btn_Cat3.Click, btn_Cat4.Click, btn_Cat5.Click, btn_Cat6.Click, btn_Cat7.Click, btn_Cat8.Click, btn_Cat9.Click, btn_Cat10.Click, btn_Cat11.Click, btn_Cat12.Click, btn_Cat13.Click, btn_Cat14.Click, btn_Cat15.Click, btn_Cat16.Click, btn_Cat17.Click, btn_Cat18.Click, btn_Cat19.Click, btn_Cat20.Click, btn_Cat21.Click
    Dim ID As Integer
    Dim btnname As String

    If Not chk = "" Then
        btnname = sender.name

        sender.text = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString
        ID = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
        dbconn()
        Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
        Dim command As MySqlCommand
        Try
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "UPDATE button_cat SET (btn_name='" & btnname & "', panelno='BLANK' WHERE idbtncat= ID')"
            command = New MySqlCommand(Query, conn)
            READER = command.ExecuteReader
            conn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            tbl_Fill()
            conn.Dispose()

        End Try


    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please Select an item from the list above first")
        chk = ""
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You have an unnecessary open paren after `SET`, but you should explain what is going wrong.  For instance, what error are you getting?

Comment: sorry Gordon, the error said "you have an error in your SQL Syntax"

Comment: Found my own mistake: Query = "UPDATE button_cat SET btn_name='" & btnname & "', panelno='BLANK' WHERE idbtncat='" & ID & "'"

Answer (score 0):

removed the open and close parenthesis and changed the ID section of code to reflect the right sintax.

Query = "UPDATE button_cat SET btn_name='" & btnname & "', panelno='BLANK' WHERE idbtncat='" & ID & "'"